# Check if connection is open and print opened connection database name or datasource name from connection string

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, connection-string

I have to open the sql or oracle connection from different class and I am creating new class.

I have to check if sql or oracle connections are opened or not.

If connections are opened, I want to print number of opened data source name or database name from the connection string.

Anyone help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use heritage to store all your connection, to check if connection is open use this code

```
  if (myConnection != null && myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
       //you can get all information about your connection string
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from the connection itself.

```
if(connection != null && connection.state == ConnectionState.Open)
{
 // You can parse the connection string 'connection.ConnectionString' here for the DB name etc. or print a number.
}
```